# How to run ./configure command on macOS?

Tags: macos, bash, terminal, ftp, pure-ftpd

I want to install Pure-FTPd on my Mac running with `10.14.6 (18G1012)` using this manual https://download.pureftpd.org/pub/pure-ftpd/doc/README.MacOS-X

When opening the Terminal app and tying `./configure --with-pam` I get `-bash: ./configure: No such file or directory` as error message.

Why that? What am I doing wrong?

Perhaps, I have to link somewhere first like `cd /path/to/somewhere`?

**UPDATE**

I found [the following](https://coderwall.com/p/mtz3iw/configure-manually-when-installing-with-homebrew) and tried `brew install --interactive pure-ftpd ./configure --with-pam` but I'm getting `Error: invalid option: --with-pam`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Why you can't find `configure`

> Perhaps, I have to link somewhere first like `cd /path/to/somewhere?`

Yes. The command `./configure` means: Run a script called `configure` from the current working directory. You can see your current directory with `pwd` – usually it's your home folder (`/Users/your-username/` or abbreviated as `~`).

If you downloaded the software, perhaps it's at `~/Downloads/pureftpd`.

That said, I don't think you should manually attempt to compile and install software on your system if you're not familiar with how the shell works. You'd be better off using pre-compiled binaries and installation scripts like Homebrew.

#### Why the Homebrew command does not work

Your problem with Homebrew stems from the fact that you mixed two commands — `brew install` and `./configure` should not be in one line. You should rather execute the `brew install --interactive …` command first, then wait for Homebrew to give back control of the shell in interactive mode. *Now* you can run the `./configure` command, since Homebrew will have changed the directory for you.

Note that you should be able to just run `brew install pure-ftpd`. That should install the server for you.

If you're having issues configuring the server to authenticate against your system users, check out [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/1398800/pure-ftpd-connection-refused-localhost-on-high-sierra).

Comment: First, thank you very much for trying to help me. I was successfully able to install pure-ftpd with the following manual: https://superuser.com/questions/1398800#tab-top. I also was able to setup a virtual user. But I'm not able to connect with this virtual user. I think the problem is as described here: https://download.pureftpd.org/pub/pure-ftpd/doc/README.Virtual-Users. I have to compile with `--with-everything`. To do so, I followed the following manual: https://download.pureftpd.org/pub/pure-ftpd/doc/README.MacOS-X.

Comment: It seems like it's working until I'm using `make install-strip`. It also seems like it even doesn't install Pure-FTPd. I posted the Terminal output here: https://codeshare.io/arWB16. Could you please have a look at this?

Comment: The error seems to be `cp: /usr/local/sbin/_inst.44153_: Operation not permitted` — some permission issue related to how macOS secures directories. I'm not sure if you are supposed to run `make install-strip` … the Homebrew formula just does a `make install`: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/master/Formula/pure-ftpd.rb#L32

Comment: I also think so. I tried with only `make install` but there's a quite similar error: https://codeshare.io/2B4Kkx

Comment: Hm, I'm not sure I can help with that specifically. Are there any permissions problems reported when running `brew doctor`? If you could edit your question to include that last log, and briefly explain what you tried, I can also remove my answer and perhaps someone else has an idea.

Comment: `brew doctor` says that everything is okay. I finally ended up by removing Pure-FTPd and downloading this app, that works very good: https://apps.apple.com/us/app/ftp-server/id987045856. Or is there anything against using a GUI app like that?

Comment: Not at all, particularly if it gets the job done. Manually building software can be a bit complex and sometimes not worth the time. (I've been there before.)