# Cannot log in using Pure-FTPd

Tags: ftp, homebrew, pure-ftpd

I have installed Pure-FTPd on my MacOS Catalina using brew and started it using `brew services start pure-ftpd`. The configuration in `/usr/local/etc/pure-ftpd.conf` sets NoAnonymous to be no and MinUID to be 100. I have created a virtual user that is based on the system account `nobody` with a UID of 4294967294. I have also added `/usr/bin/false` to `/etc/shells`. However, I still get the following error:

```
421 Sorry, but I can't trust you
ftp: Login failed.
```

After attempting to modify the configurations and creating slightly modified virtual users several times, I shifted my attempt to logging in to FTP as anonymous. However, I got the following error:

```
Unable to set up secure anonymous FTP
```

I have checked out the FAQ for Pure-FTPd and it seems that I have addressed all potential causes of the above two errors. Any suggestions on how I can log in to FTP?

Comment: did you ever figure out?

Answer (score 1):

i follow the steps in the following thread
[pure-ftpd Connection refused localhost on high sierra](https://superuser.com/questions/1398800/pure-ftpd-connection-refused-localhost-on-high-sierra)

1. I have stopped the service(Also check in Activity Monitor to ensure no other instance of `pureftpd` running).

```
$ brew services stop pure-ftpd
```

2. I have remove to service

```
$ brew remove pure-ftpd
```

3. I have updated brew

```
$ brew upgrade
```

4. I have cleaned it

```
$ brew cleanup
```

5. I have reinstalled it

```
$ brew install pure-ftpd
```

6. I have created the `/etc/pam.d/pure-ftpd` following lines using root privilege:

```
# pure-ftpd: auth account password session
auth       required       pam_opendirectory.so
account    required       pam_permit.so
password   required       pam_deny.so
session    required       pam_permit.so
```

7. Set pam configuration

```
sudo /usr/local/sbin/pure-ftpd -lpam -B
```

8. I have restart the service

```
$ brew services restart pure-ftpd
```

9. And finally the connection has successfully!

```
$ ftp localhost
Trying ::1...
Connected to localhost.
220---------- Welcome to Pure-FTPd [privsep] [TLS] ----------
220-You are user number 1 of 50 allowed.
220-Local time is now 20:42. Server port: 21.
220 You will be disconnected after 15 minutes of inactivity.
Name (localhost:alexandre1202): 
331 User alexandre1202 OK. Password required
Password: 
230 OK. Current directory is /Users/alexandre1202
Remote system type is UNIX.
Using binary mode to transfer files.
ftp>
```